# Using Refactor fields (Batch processing): error in "Fields mapping" column

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, batch, vector-layer

I have several layers and want to delete some of their table attributes columns, like *FLAG*. Using **Refactor fields** is fine:

[image: Refactor fields]

However, when I do it in batch, I get an error in the **Fields mapping** column which doesn't recognize *FLAG*:

```
Missing parameter value: Fields mapping (row 1)
```

[image: Fields mapping error]

I was hoping to use the tool in batch as I have several columns I want to have deleted in many of my layers.

Comment: @mgri This question by JAT86 was the first. Please see below answer and comment by gisinside, who later posted new question focusing on the syntax.

Comment: @mgri I posted the question you point out to be able to answer specifically to this one : I was sure it was a syntax problem, but couldn't find the right way of writing it. thanks for your detailed answer by the way. I'll update mine below to answer JAT later when I have a bit of time to try it :)

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't answer the question, but as a simple answer to your real need, I suggest you'd rather use the Delete Column Tool in Batch mode :

[image: Delete batch]

For your question, I think **your syntax of the "field mapping" box is not correct**. Field are often with double quotes "FLAG" for example. To delete a column, just don't include it in the field mapping and it won't appear in the generated layer.

(I'm looking for the syntax of the field mapping field but I haven't found an answer yet. I'll update here when I find)

Comment: I posted a new question on the syntax to be used in fields mapping to be able to answer you : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/254846/whats-the-refactor-tool-field-mapping-syntax-in-qgis