# What's the batched Refactor Fields tool "field mapping" syntax in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, vector, qgis-processing, batch

In QGIS, there is this nice tool **"Refactor Fields"** in the Processing Toolbox :

[image: Refactor Fields tool]

Using it on a single layer is fairly straightforward.

However, when you plan on using it in a batch mode, one can see the **"Fields mapping"** textbox. I'm looking for an **example of the syntax to be used there**.  I haven't found any specific documentation yet.

[image: Refactor batched]

Comment: After run a refactoring from the GUI, you can watch the command in the Processing -> History menu (Ctrl+Alt+H)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not very comfortable to do, but the following is the required syntax for that textbox (I write it in several lines only for the sake of clearness):

```py
{'expression': u'type the expression here',
 'length': <type the length>,
 'type': <code of the type>,
 'name': u'type the field name here',
 'precision': <type the precision>}
```

For example (remeber to use curly brackets):

```py
{'expression': u'"FLAG1"+"FLAG2"',
 'length': 20, 'type': 6,
 'name': u'FLAG1',
 'precision': 5}
```

You need to write as many lines like the one above as the number of input fields, separated by commas. For example, if your layer contains three fields:

```py
{'expression': u'"FLAG1"+"FLAG2"', 'length': 20, 'type': 6, 'name': u'FLAG1', 'precision': 5}, {'expression': u'100*"FLAG2"', 'length': 20, 'type': 6, 'name': u'FLAG2', 'precision': 5}, {'expression': u'"100-"FLAG2"', 'length': 20, 'type': 6, 'name': u'FLAG3', 'precision': 5}
```

and it should work (it worked for me).

Please note that you may avoid to use this *dictionary-oriented* syntax and directly use the required values. For example, with reference to the first example, you may simply use:

```py
{u'"FLAG1"+"FLAG2"', 20, 6, u'FLAG1', 5}
```

If you don't use this syntax, the following error will be shown:

> Missing parameter value: Fields mapping (row 1)

Comment: Can you please explain what <code of the type> means? I tried using 3 assuming it is for string (as it is the 3rd in the dropdown options) but I got an error: 'int' object has no attribute '___getItem___' See log for more details. The code I used is:{u'"FLAG"', 0, 3, u'FLAG', 0} for one of my layers where {'expression': u'"FLAG"', 'length': 0, 'type': 3, 'name': u'FLAG', 'precision': 0}.

Comment: @JAT86 It is the number that identifies the data type (i.e. int, string and so on). Unfortunately, I didn't find a reference for them, but I should remember the values for the most used types: **2** for int, **6** for double and **10** for string. In addition to this, maybe you should not specify `0` for the field length (at least `1`!). Please, let me know if you solved the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. Perhaps the batch processing is much more complex than I had thought. I tried using at least 1 for the length and 10 for type of code: {u'"FLAG"', 1, 10, u'FLAG', 0} Still, the error shows up: 'int' object has no attribute 'getItem' See log for more details. My layer has the following attributes: **name:** flag,**Type:** string, **Length:** 0, **Precision:** 0, **Expression:** "flag"

Comment: @JAT86 Does running the tool from the GUI return any problem?

Comment: If by GUI you mean a single layer, no it did not have any problems. The FLAG column was successfully deleted upon "clicking Delete selected field" and was saved into a new layer "Refactored".

Answer (score 2):

There is another algorithm similar to this whose interface simplifies the batch process better.

[image]

Comment: English english

Comment: The english translation for the menu item in question is "Add field to attribute table"